# SQL Server 2014 Evaluation database to SQL Server 2014 Express?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I have taken over a client, who had an inhouse developer. The inhouse developer used SQL Server 2014 Evaluation (which I believe/assume is Enterprise)?

Regardless, their SQL Server eval has now expired, and they are "locked" into buying SQL Server, as their whole app infrastructure now sits in SQL Server 2014.

Will the database of an evaluation version of SQL Server, spool up in a SQL Server 2014 Express version?

I don't right now have the architecture at hand to test this scenario, and would like some ideas around the best way to resolve this. As it is now, they are dead in the water.

The client does not need anything specific to 2014 Standard or enterprise version for that matter (to my knowledge), and they are only about 30 users, using the app inhouse.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it fits within the constraints of Sql Server Express edition, yes.

There are CPU, memory, and database size restrictions as well as some feature restrictions

See Microsoft website for edition comparison: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx

Once you've installed SQL Express, you should be able to just attach the database files to Express Edition, or backup and restore. see: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx

Comment: but anyhow i want to migrate data from evaluation version to express version.

Comment: you should be able to just attach the database files to Express Edition, or backup and restore. see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx

Comment: glad it helped... be sure to mark this as the accepted answer and vote it up then, that way it'll help someone else in case they don't read the comments (I edited my answer with my comment that actually solved your issue)